# error: could not build Objective-C module 'Foundation'

Tags: ios, swift3, compiler-errors

I encounter this 2 errors while archiving my project. I don't know what happen on it. Need help to solve this issues.

[image]

Foundation framework already added into the project

[image]

Comment: Is it just this project on the Mac? What does a sample project do (e.g. file -> new -> single page application)

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Yes, but when i'm run it simulator the project build successfully

Comment: I'm tempted to say that your library might be corrupt. Also have you updated to Xcode 9, that is available now.

Comment: @MitchellCurrie Perhaps, I'm still using Xcode 8.3.3

Comment: Having the same issue in the static library gives error when build for Generic devices, works fine for the simulator, even if I remove import Foundation it builds successful for generic devices.

Answer (score -1):

First try by full clean with,

```
(Command-Option-Shift-K)
```

then if it will not done then

Once try like below,

Select your project name(top most row in left side panel) from navigator - > go to `build settings` -> `Apple LLVM 8.1 - Languages - Modules` -> set `Enable modules(C and Objective-C)` to `NO`.

Here `8.1` is your xcode version number if you are using xcode 9 then it will be `Apple LLVM 9.0` instead of `Apple LLVM 8.1`.

Comment: appreciated for ur reply, I've set the Enable modules(C and Objective-C) to NO but it still show the same error message :(